# masked TextBox with unlimited mask

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a masked textbox where the user is only allowed to enter alphanumeric letters.

But how can I get the amount of letters to be entered unlimited, so any number of letters can be entered and not restricted to the mask?

```
        nameTextBox.ValidatingType = typeof(System.Char);
        nameTextBox.TypeValidationCompleted += new        TypeValidationEventHandler(nameTextBox_TypeValidationCompleted);
```

Comment: you mean to say, you should be able to enter non-alphanumeric letters too??

Comment: @Manish no, I validated it just to letters, but want to be able to enter different amount of letters

so for example aaaaa on first submition
then aaaaaaaaaaa on the next submition

Comment: so have you placed a validation on length aswell?? cross-check whether the TextBox's MaxLength is sufficiently large

Comment: thats not what I mean. 
the texbox contains for example: _______

 if only aaaaaa___ is filled out it would not let me submit. how can is disable the length restriction

Comment: why it would not let you submit? have you placed a check on its length?? if yes then remove it or increase the length value

Comment: show your validation code

Comment: it is limited because of the mask which is set in the properties

Answer (score 0):

The MaskedTextBox does not support the MaxLength property, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.maxlength.aspx). You must specify a mask with a specific length, for example 'LLLLL' for any 5 characters. If you want an arbitrary length, you will probably have to use a regular TextBox instead and hook up eventhandlers for Validating and TextChanged. In order to give the user feedback you can add a label next to the TextBox with information on valid chars and if it is currently valid or not.

For a quick-and-dirty solution, you can try this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var originalText = myMaskedTextBox.Text;
    var parsedText = Regex.Replace(myMaskedTextBox.Text, "[^a-z_A-Z]", "");

    if (originalText == parsedText)
        labelInfo.Text = "Valid string";
    else
    {
        myMaskedTextBox.Text = parsedText;
        labelInfo.Text = "Only alpha-numeric characters please";    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot is there anywhere clear i can find how to do this

Comment: Added a small example. You will have to add some extra code to create a nice Gui, but the code will remove any non-alphanumeric characters dynamically. The caret position will be placed at the beginning of the TextBox so you might want to add some logic to remember the old position and reset if and illegal characters were removed.

Comment: Added some more code, it will also handle any pasted text. Good luck!